# Database Schema help needed for a social networking site

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm in middle of creating a social networking site something like facebook, and got struck up with database schema design for it.. from previous questions i posted here, i confirmed that i cant create new database or tables for a new user who registers onto my site. I need to insert new row [thats my only option(correct me if i'm wrong!)]. but, this works out for registration for the first time. what if the user posts something new on his profile.. where should i insert this update.. coz, i cant insert them into rows as dey correspond to each user.. and too many columns cannot be created.. what is the solution for this.?

schema =>

TableName : User_content

userId Name College City Status_Updates Messages

1       a     sfd    fds    fsds           sdds
2        f    dfg     dfd    fdf           dfd

what if user 1 updates something.. what i need to do nw. Think its a status update, how to go about it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tables based on what you want to allow your users to do and the related data you need to store as a result. Some example tables:

- 'user_account': User account information (e-mail address, password) - referenced by user ID
- 'user_profile': Basic user profile information - referenced by user ID
- 'user_status': User status message - referenced by user ID

I have the sense that this is your first major database application, and if so, you need to learn more about database design in general before you take on creating an application like this. There are many things to consider when designing a database schema and designing it well from the start is key. The core of your application will rely on how well your data is organized and accessible, so ensure you spend enough time developing a good design.

Good luck!

Comment: hi bernard.. yea, this is my first db project of this scale.. i'm good at basics n theory of DBMS but still i'm not able to track the implementation part of it.. suggest me some references to understand this practical implementational features of a project of similar kind.

Comment: hi wait.. if i can do as u said, i.e by creating 3 tables for each user.. den if der are 100000 users in my site, then totally they will become 300000 tables.. is it ok?

Comment: Do not create tables for each user. For example, use the three tables I outlined above for *all* users and store one row of data for each user in each table. Each row will be uniquely identified by a user ID, making it possible to retrieve the data for a specific user. Not to discourage you, but this is one of the fundamental things you should know when creating a database schema. I strongly suggest you create a simple schema first, with a few tables, and implement the most basic functionality for your application.

Answer (score 3):

Before you start thinking about this social network site you dream if
Developing you need to understand database modelling fundamentals. This link will help you with some simple concepts. http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_data_modelling/index.htm